# SproutCore IPAD

Tags: ipad, sproutcore

I am working on a SproutCore project. I am trying to get the site as is on the IPAD, but the CSS background images, onClick and redirect is not working on the IPAD.

Let me know any solution on this.

Comment: This sounds like three separate questions. 1) I'm posting an answer about onClick below. 2) I've successfully used CSS backgrounds and spriting and so on on the iPad without modification in the past, so we'll need to know more about your specific case and problem before we can help. 3) can you clarify the "redirect" issue?

Comment: Follow-up question on click events: are you using SC.ButtonView, or building your own views? If you have any SC.ButtonView, can you specify whether they work correctly on the iPad? They should.

Comment: @Dave ButtonView works great on IPAD, but the real issue is with the image sprites. I've used touchStart instead of mouseDown, that made the app work on ipad, but images are still not loading.

Answer (score 0):

When developing on the iPad, I have found the following to be useful in my `Buildfile`:

```
mode :debug do
  config :all, :combine_javascript => true
end
```

Most iOS devices tend to have difficulty loading a large number of Javascript files, and this will concatenate them all into one. This may or may not resolve your issues, but many issues manifest if you leave them as separate files.

Also, do you have any errors in the debugger that you could share? It might help us track down the issue.

Comment: Hi @Topher Fangio , 

Thank you for reply. I've tried this but not helped. There are no error messages on the debugged.

On IPAD issue is with the CSS background image and with the onClick events. These both are not working as desired.

Comment: Can you use http://gist.github.com to show the code that isn't working properly so that we can test it ourselves and find the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't share the code :-( . But you can test my app at [site link](https://perzoclarion.appspot.com) . Please let me know once you  find the link, I need to remove it from here.

Comment: Dave, please look at the code below, I am having issue with this code. 
`code`
logout: function() {
    $.colorbox({html: '<div class="inlineInformation"><h2>Are you sure you want to logout?</h2><a class="floatLeft cancelit pointer"></a><a class="floatRight logout pointer"></a></div>', width:'600', opacity: 0.6, open:true});
      $('.logout').click(function(){
        Home.windowController.playSound('Logout', function(){
          window.location.href = '/logout';
        });
      });

      $('.cancelit').click(function() {
        $.colorbox.close();
      })
  }

Comment: I visited the link, but the background image and buttons all appear to be working properly on my original iPad. Which buttons are not working?

Comment: It will be good if you can check the page simultaneously on desktop and IPAD. It will be more helpful this way.

Comment: I did indeed visit on both the Desktop and iPad and it looked identical. Do I need to login and create an account in order to see the issues?

Comment: yes @Topher, you need to create account. I was trying to resolve this issue and found that image sprites are not loading on IPAD.

Answer (score 0):

For broken images/CSS after building, it's often a relative path issue.

You might want to check your CSS / image paths in your compiled CSS & index.html files.

After building the project, look inside your output directory and try the following:

- Open index.html file in your browser, and see which CSS/image files are not loading correctly.
- Find your index.html file and replace instances of "/static" with "static"
- Find stylesheet-packed.css & stylesheet@2x-packed.css and replace instances of "/static" with "../../../static" (or whatever fixes the path in your case)

I have build.sh script to automate this and it works for me. Let me know if you want it.. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @tompos, images and css loads perfectly for Web browsers on Machine, issue is with the IPAD devices. Background images and onclick events dont works for IPAD in my case.